# change disk cache settings on Samsung PM9A3 via nvme-cli

Tags: cache, zfs, ssd, nvme

I will be running Proxmox guests on a ZFS volume consisting of Samsungs PM9A3 NVME drives. I [read here for ex.](https://serverfault.com/questions/995702/zfs-enable-or-disable-disk-cache) it might be an advantage in performance to keep the cache of those drives active.

So I just wanted to check if that is the case but I seem to lack some skills here. I tried `nvme get-feature -f 0x06 /dev/nvme0n1` - checking feature No. 6 - which should with most drives return the value of disk cache present or not. Not with my drives, it returns `NVMe status: Invalid Field in Command: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field(0x2)` Features like 0x05 return values as expected. In total, there are only 15 features present here.

So I checked with `nvme id-ctrl /dev/nvme0n1 -H` which returns the full set of features the drive supports. Here you go with an excerpt that shows besides a few others the section of "Volatile Write Cache" which is Samsung's expression for the disk cache.

```
  [2:1] : 0x3   The Flush command supports NSID set to FFFFFFFFh
  [0:0] : 0     Volatile Write Cache Not Present

fna       : 0x4
  [3:3] : 0     Format NVM Broadcast NSID (FFFFFFFFh) Supported
  [2:2] : 0x1   Crypto Erase Supported as part of Secure Erase
  [1:1] : 0     Crypto Erase Applies to Single Namespace(s)
  [0:0] : 0     Format Applies to Single Namespace(s)

awun      : 1023
awupf     : 7
icsvscc   : 1
  [0:0] : 0x1   NVM Vendor Specific Commands uses NVMe Format

nwpc      : 0
  [2:2] : 0     Permanent Write Protect Not Supported
  [1:1] : 0     Write Protect Until Power Supply Not Supported
  [0:0] : 0     No Write Protect and Write Protect Namespace Not Supported
```

Unfortunately I fail in interpreting this properly so I am not sure if I could adress any of this with the get-feature / set-feature command .. Last try using the identifiers as subcommands like `nvme samsung vwc /dev/nvme1` also does not seem to work with the drives.

AND it reads like cache is NOT active.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it states "not present".

Comment: So do you think the drive does not possess any cache? From what I read [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/ssd-specs/samsung-pm9a3-1-9-tb.d1258) and also at [Samsung`s](https://images.samsung.com/is/content/samsung/assets/pl/memory-storage/PM9A3-NVMe-U.2-Datasheet_for-07_v1.5.pdf), section "SPOR", it looks like there should be one ..

Answer (score 1):

Samsung PM9A3 SSDs provide a powerloss-protected write back cache via dedicated capacitors.

This means these disks have no volatile write cache. Rather, they provide data persistency for cached data (ie: they have a non-volatile cache).

The line

`[0:0] : 0     Volatile Write Cache Not Present`

confirms the above.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get it. Non-volatile cache would not need any caps I would guess. Did you check the [link I provided at Techpowerup](https://www.techpowerup.com/ssd-specs/samsung-pm9a3-1-9-tb.d1258) which even shows pictures of the DRAM chips and states 5x512MB of capacity?

Comment: A volatile DRAM cache can be made *non-volatile* by the means of battery or capacitors. Do you see the huge gray capacitors on the very same link you provided? When a powerloss is detected they are used to store any cached data into permanent NAND, ensuring no data loss.

Comment: OK, so you say I don't have the option to disable caching because it is protected by the powerloss feature? Possible but a bit weird. Are there no other reasons besides powerloss protection to disable caching?